# finding variance of gaussian distribution from mean

Tags: probability, normal-distribution

The Gaussian random variable $X$ can be used to model the number of customers that enter a market in 1 minute at a given time of the day. The mean number of customers that enter the market in 1 minute is 10 and the probability that fewer than 3 customers enter the market in 1 minute is $ 0.035 $. What is the probability that more than 12 customers enter the market in 1 minute. Also determine $f_X(x|X>12)$ ?

I couldn't find variance. So i couldn't solve this problem

Thanks in advance.

Comment: does this give you a clue about what you are looking for? the probability that fewer than 3 customers enter the market in 1 minute is 0.035.  btw what kind of Guassian is that? because -3 customers is a valid number for the Gaussian distribution.

Answer (score 1):

As @Seyhmus Güngören points out, you have been asked to solve
a drill problem that is not likely to be useful in practice. 
So it may be difficult for you to have an intuitive sense
how to proceed. Here is the approach I think you are
expected to take.

$$0.035 = P(X \le 3) = P(Z \le (3 - 10)/\sigma),$$

where $Z$ is standard normal. From normal tables (or from software) you can find
$P(Z \le -1.8119) = 0.035.$ From there you should be
able to find the value of $\sigma.$

Notes: (1) Maybe you'd be asked to use $(3.5 - 10)/\sigma$ in the
displayed equation. (2) The resulting normal distribution with mean 10 and $\sigma$
as computed above has almost half a percent of its area below 0.
So this normal distribution is is hardly a realistic model
for numbers of people entering the market. Not only that, the
number of people is discrete and the normal distribution is
continuous. A more realistic model would use the Poisson 
distribution, which you may study later.

Comment: Thanks for reply. How can i solve $f_X(x|X>12)$ ?